# 1999 ford f150 4x4 extended cab...bogged down moving rpms and misfiring

Tags: engine, ford, f-150, hesitation

I have a 1999 ford f150 4x4 and i have been having issues with hesitation When i accelerate. I took it to have codes read and it said that 7 n 8 are misfiring and and something like FBR..FDR...something is working right. And one of my ignition coil packs had to be replaced. I replaced the coil pack and got a new spark plug......but NOW it seems like its worae AND now it has no get up and go. I can push it to the floor and it takes forever for it to go anywhere.
I do know that my fly wheel is missing a tooth because of that erry grinding sound it make when i go to start it sometimes.. I also know i do have a hole in my exhaust..can that cause thisbpro

.what can be causing all this?
   Is it the O2 sensor?
Is it the throttle body sensor?
   Is it the catalytic coconvert being clogged?
Is it the fuel pump going out?
   Is it the fuel body sensor?
 Can someone please help me out

Comment: Sounds like it needs all the plugs changed. A full tuneup may help. What were the actual codes?

Comment: Also, fixing the stuff you know is bad (ie: leaking exhaust) can do nothing but help you narrow down what might be going on.